# first line in array (within a align) - first command are broken

Tags: align, siunitx

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\percent}{\%}
\begin{document}
            \begin{align}
                A_{B} 
                & = \left\{%
                    \begin{array}%
                        \SI{0,51}{\percent} \text{\quad for \quad} -\beta \\
                        \SI{0,58}{\percent} \text{\quad for \quad} +\beta.
                    \end{array}
                    \right. \notag
            \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compiles to

[image]

How to get the % and the format also in the first line?

Comment: never ignore errors, if you scroll past an error TeX does not attempt to make a usable PDF it just carries on so you can check for later errors. The output of your test file is `! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\SI): `c' used.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the argument with the column specifiers for `array` (and you get error messages from this), but there's a better way.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\percent}{\%}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A_{B} =
\begin{cases}
  \SI{0,51}{\percent} & \text{for } -\beta \\
  \SI{0,58}{\percent} & \text{for } +\beta.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `align` for a single equation, only when there are multiple ones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. And also for the hint with cases. I didn't know this option before, but it is exactly the right one for this case. I am aware that align is for multiple lines. I stripped my code to a MWE, so the align is wrong here, but right in my full code.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `{array}` is wrong.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\percent}{\%}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A_{B} 
    & = \left\{%
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            \SI{0,51}{\percent} & \text{for} & -\beta \\
            \SI{0,58}{\percent} & \text{for} & +\beta.
        \end{array}
        \right. \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Unfortunately I can only approve one solution.